# Scroll to element when redirected using <Link> React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code which redirects to a component when clicked,

```
<Link to="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}>
   Click Here
</Link>
```

Clicking on this takes me to the Dashboard component but I want it to scroll down automatically to a particular element in the Dashboard component.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, on the element in `/dashboard` define an ID.
Then when redirecting use:

```
<Link to="/dashboard#id-of-the-element" component={Dashboard}>
   Click Here
</Link>
```

This will then scroll down the page to where that element is defined